# java design problem for validations

Tags: java, xml, validation

I have the following requirement:
I have a validation system.  One of the things that I need to do is perform validations on XML files, meaning validating that tag X equals a given value.  I have more than one possible scenario, and in each scenario there is a different set of tags that need to be validated.

I don't want to repeat same code when testing same tags in different scenarios.

I'm trying to figure out a design that will solve this issue.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I'd define pairs of XPath expressions and expected results for the scenarios.

The validator then would take a scenario (object), compile and apply the associated  expressions to the xml document. This would select an element and the validator would check, if the element's content matches the expected value.

Comment: thanks for the answer. the expected results are determined at runtime. so i cant predefine the expressions and the results.

Comment: @dan - doesn't matter - then just store the XPaths and tell your validator at runtime *where* to get the expected results or the rules

Answer (score 0):

Erm, delegate to a shared method? Like:

```
void validateAppleScenario(Xml xml) {
    validateFruit(xml);
    // validate apples specific tags
}

void validateBanana(Xml xml) {
    validateFruit(xml);
    // validate banana specific tags
}

void validateFruit(Xml xml) {
    // validate tags common to all fruit
}
```

Or if you prefer validators to be seperate objects, you can use subtyping:

```
interface Validator {
    void validate(Xml xml);
}

class FruitValidator implements Validator {
    void validate(Xml xml) {
        // validate tags common to all fruit
    }
}

class AppleValidator extends FruitValidator {
    void validate(Xml xml) {
        super.validate(xml);
        // validate tags specific to apples
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to parse the XML into an object and then validate it in accordance with Bean Validation spec (JSR 303).  [Hibernate Validator](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/) is the reference implementation.*  You can annotate your properties with validation constraints, and then specify [validation groups](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html/validator-usingvalidator.html#validator-usingvalidator-validationgroups) so that certain fields get validated in certain scenarios.

There is more info [here](http://java.dzone.com/articles/bean-validation-and-jsr-303) and [here](http://wheelersoftware.com/articles/hibernate-validator.html).

*Hibernate Validator is different from Hibernate ORM. They're only related in that Hibernate ORM uses Validator for its constraint checking.